# algolia how to orderby string-value and geolocation

Tags: algolia

I am working on a prototype for a new product, need some help to figure out algolia feasibility. I did go through their documentation but couldn't find right answer. Any help appreciated.

Best example of our data is classified. In dataset we have geolocation(lat-lng) and category

```
[ 
     {
        category: 'retail_shops',
        "_geoloc": {
             "lat": 40.639751,
             "lng": -73.778925
        },
        title: 'walget1'
     },
     {
        category: 'retail_shops',
        "_geoloc": {
             "lat": 40.639751,
             "lng": -73.778925
        },
        title: 'walget1'
     },
]
```

Search Requirement

- sortby category, selected category first, then all other in anyorder
- sortby geolocation, this is secondary filter

We need to display all data in the system but selected category first and distance as secondary.

I am trying to do this is javascript, did find find search and searchForFacetValues methods but documentation is all-around. Any ideal how to achieve this? don't need code but general guidance will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so, you can use a `multiple-queries` strategy, where you would have a query with a filter that matches the category, and then another query that matches all objects not in the category. In the query parameters you can then use the `aroundLatLng` field or the `aroundLatLngViaIp` field.

The following snippet should help you get a better understanding of how to achieve what you want:

```js
const client = algoliasearch('ApplicationID', 'apiKey');

// these two values would be obtained from somewhere (like InstantSearch)
const query = 'walg';
const category = 'retail_shops';

const queries = [{
  indexName: 'products',
  query: `${query}`,
  params: {
    hitsPerPage: 3,
    filters: `category:${category}`,
    aroundLatLngViaIP:true
  }
}, {
  indexName: 'products',
  query: `${query}`,
  params: {
    hitsPerPage: 10,
    filters: `NOT category:${category}`,
    aroundLatLngViaIP:true
  }
}];

const searchCallback = (err, content) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  const categorySpecificResults = content.results[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < categorySpecificResults.hits.length; ++i) {
    console.log(categorySpecificResults.hits[i]);
  }

  const geolocatedOnlyResults = content.results[1];
  for (var i = 0; i < geolocatedOnlyResults.hits.length; ++i) {
    console.log(geolocatedOnlyResults.hits[i]);
  }
}

// perform the 2 queries in a single API call:
//  - 1st query targets index `products` with category filter and geolocation
//  - 2nd query targets index `products` with negative category filter and geolocation
client.search(queries, searchCallback);
```

You will find more information about how to use multiple queries on this page:

- [How to use multiple Queries](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/multiple-queries/)

If you want a more fine grained control on the geolocation, like for instance defining a precision or a maximum range for the search, you can find more about these different features on these pages:

- [aroundLatLng](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/aroundLatLng/): used when you want to define the geographical center of your query
- [aroundRadius](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/aroundRadius/): used to limit a search to a certain range around the center of the query
- [aroundPrecision](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/aroundPrecision/): defines how precise the ranking has to be when it comes to distance.